# Suggested edit to post without punctuation marks or sentence separation rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edit, specific-answer

I suggested an edit to an [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224743/doesnt-data-know-the-kobayashi-maru/224754#224754) that completely lacked any punctuation marks (save for two commas), with sentences just chained together without any separation whatsoever:

> Strategema is not a no win situation to be fair technically neither is the Maru, it is a competitive game of some sort while the game is never explained in depth the visuals make it look a little like go with territory control being key however it also appears to be played in real time and it appears that each finger controls some kind of input Data concludes that he is damaged because as an Android his reflexes, visual acuity and mental acuity should be superior to any biological entity
>
> Basically Data has an existential crisis when one of his core beliefs is proven wrong

The suggested edit:

> Strategema is not a no-win situation and, to be fair, technically neither is the Maru. Strategema is a competitive game of some sort. While the game is never explained in depth, the visuals make it look a little like Go with territory control being key; however it also appears to be played in real time and it appears that each finger controls some kind of input. Data concludes that he is damaged because as an android his reflexes, visual acuity and mental acuity should be superior to any biological entity.
>
> Basically Data has an existential crisis when one of his core beliefs is proven wrong.

with punctuation marks, sentence separation, and the first letter of the word 'Go' capitalized, to clarify that it is the game (and not the verb).

As it happens, both reviewers [rejected](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/157534) the edit with the same rationale:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I would really like to hear opinions here - isn't the edited text much easier to read than the first one? Or was it a bad suggestion?

Comment: Hmm.  Just commenting because I didn't review, but I probably would have accepted the edit just for clarifying the antecedent of the "it" following the first comma.  (Normal grammatical rules would suggest its antecedent should be "the Maru," which is obviously incorrect.)

Comment: @DavidW indeed (among other things)

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't read too much into the specific message; it's one of only 4 or so canned responses, and the only one that is remotely applicable.  You're not causing harm, not applying inappropriate tags and not attempting to reply.

Comment: @DavidW thanks, Appreciate the reassurance, but it would seem that I cause harm to my time, suggesting such useless edits :(

Comment: That looks like a good edit to me. I have no idea why anyone would reject it.

Comment: Mistake on my part here, I saw the tags and missed it was an answer somehow and cos you didn’t fix the tags I rejected as it wasn’t a complete edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot copy, but not sure why you think the existing tags `star-trek-tng`, `star-trek-data`, and `kobayashi-maru` needed any fixing at all (no one has attempted to edit them, either).

Comment: Missing the franchise/universe tag, [[tag:star-trek]].

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot OK, added as a suggested edit; arguably, it would be more productive if you had attempted to improve the edit yourself, instead of rejecting it (that way, you would have discovered that it was about the answer, and not the question).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot That's not a reason to reject an edit. If someone is making an edit which is *good* (improves the post) but not *complete* (doesn't improve every possible thing which could be improved), that's what the "Improve Edit" button is for, not the "Reject" button.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Depends on the particular edit of course and it’s a judgement call to be made.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot please leave "*it depends*" arguments for general discussions, where they certainly have a place; here we are talking for a specific edit, and your equally specific rationale for rejecting it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Did you miss that the person telling you how you are supposed to vote has a diamond by their name? A mod is telling you that you did it wrong.

Comment: @trlkly I’ve admitted I was at fault and explained why I did what I did. I’m also not going to roll over just because a mod says something. We all know mods are not 100% perfect and neither am I. I’ve said I was sorry for rejecting it, I don’t see much point in piling on to be honest.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Piling on is arguably not the correct description here, since your explanation obviously created a new issue. "*Sorry, I was wrong*" would be perfectly fine; "*sorry, I thought it was a question, so given that I rightfully rejected it cos it was not complete*", is another story, and not much of an admission of fault actually.

Comment: I said sorry and explained why I did what I did. If you’d rather I just said sorry with no explanation then I don’t see the point in the meta.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot the point in the Meta is exactly to discuss actions, point out possible mistakes (both in actions and rationale), and explain why they are so. Some Meta threads become canon, as obviously the help system cannot cover everything. Indeed I appreciate offering your rationale here, as this permitted to highlight why it is wrong (beyond a trivial issue of mistaking an answer to a question, for which I do accept your apologies), thus making the thread more general and more valuable for others in the future. This, i.e. the future, will show if this message was well received, too.

Comment: For what it worths, *go* shouldn't be capitalised. It's not a proper name and the OP's style of writing doesn't suggest emphatic capitalisation. Go is a game like chess or draughts or tarot: ordinary nouns.

Comment: @elemtilas although formally you are right (not a proper name indeed), it would seem that in practice ([popular](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2017/10/alphago-zero-the-ai-that-taught-itself-go/543450/) press [articles](https://www.theverge.com/2019/11/27/20985260/ai-go-alphago-lee-se-dol-retired-deepmind-defeat), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)), scientific [literature](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature16961)) it is very often capitalized.

Comment: Yeah.  Mind you, I wouldn't trust the press as arbiter of what's right. Better idea is to simply italicise it, if you consider it a foreign word; or leave it alone if you consider it sufficiently nativised.

Comment: @elemtilas as already said, I have referenced what is often the case, not what is right (and not sure if *Nature* can be considered "press", in the sense that you seem to mean here). Leaving it alone is of course always an option.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The consensus in the discussion seems clear in that the suggested edit improved the post, hence it should have not be rejected.

One of the reviewers was kind enough to offer their explanation for rejecting the edit: they mistakenly thought that the post was a question, and not an answer; given that, their rationale was to reject the edit because it was not complete (i.e. it didn't address an additional tag issue). Nevertheless

> That's not a reason to reject an edit. If someone is making an edit which is *good* (improves the post) but not *complete* (doesn't improve every possible thing which could be improved), that's what the "Improve Edit" button is for, not the "Reject" button.

as convincingly argued by a moderator in the comments above.